# is it possible to update the query string in the browser either client or server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a website written in asp.net MVC2 that shows random images, each image has an ID and the first image is a random one, however the url the visitor sees when viewing this image does not have the imageid. i want to make it so that when the user visits www.mydomain.com the query string will be updated to be something like www.mydomain.com/?imageid=12.

this way they can forward on what they see to others.

I dont mind if i set this with javascript, on the server side, or as a response redirect.

Comment: Please clarify: user enters main page like 'mydomain.com/', then on server side some random image is selected and it's url put into page source, right? then you may have 2 options: create param imageId in action and check it on server side; upload image url on client using JS onload and specify it as #imageId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but it would work, I suppose

```
window.onload = function(){
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); //get all images
    var first = images[0]; //get the first of all images
    var imgid = first.id;  //get the id of the first one
    window.location = "www.mydomain.com?imageid="+imgid;
}
```

Comment: I agree with Mike's comment above. My explanation is based on an the limited info you gave in the question. Good luck!

Comment: that will redirect browser to different page - additional server logic required

Comment: ok figured out how to do this, sorry for the poor explanation to the problem

Comment: I agree. Not perfect. Not sure that this solution is perfect either. If it were me, I would look at the HttpResponse class and see what you can do to do to set page params there. I am not a C# buff... so I am not sure.